# Dual Monitors switch theme/wallpaper

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I have recently purchased a new, secondary monitor for my laptop. I have set up my desktop wallpaper by placing 2 images side by side, so they spread across both screens.

However, I often choose not to use my second monitor, and when I unplug it, my original desktop gets set to the combined image.

How could I automatically set my desktop background to a single image when I have no second monitor, and then set it to a double image when I do?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having both the backgrounds as separate images for this,

1. Go into Desktop Background.
2. Load/Browse the folder with the 2 images in it.
3. Right click the images and select the monitor you want to display it on.
4. Do #3 for the second image.

(You can check via the Screen Resolution settings window to see your monitor numbers)

This way when you disconnect lets say, monitor 2, everything comes back to the monitor 1 and monitor 1's wallpaper should remain the same as it was set previously.

Steps confirmed to work on Win 8.1 as I have 2 separate wallpapers in this config currently.

Comment: I didn't realise this was possible! I wonder why most tutorials do this in other, weird ways...